# Tabs using Jquery and CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs

I copied the code from here. 
    http://jsfiddle.net/syahrasi/Us8uc/.

```
<div id="tabs-container">
    <ul class="tabs-menu">
        <li class="current"><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-4">Tab 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab">
        <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">

        </div>
        <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">


        </div>
        <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">

        </div>
        <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason, which I can't seem to find, its showing like this. 
    http://postimg.org/image/ejs26rx3t/

I tried my best, but can't make it to appear as it's showing in the fiddle. Plz help.

Comment: add please some page with your css and js code on jsfiddle. It seams that something wrong with your css styles. Please check css and problem be fixed.

Comment: try adding `display: inline-block` to `tabs-container` or add a clear div before the closing div of `tabs-container`

Answer (score 1):

The Fiddle includes the `normalize.css` as you'll notice when using web dev tools and e.g. inspect the `ul` element - the `list-style: outside none none;` is set in line 21 of the normalize.css. You can google for normalize.css to download and include in your page.

The normalize.css used in the Fiddle is this one: http://jsfiddle.net/css/normalize.css

Comment: I had already tried that, it just takes off the bullets from the list items. The content area is still showing outside.

Comment: @dr_dev Is it possible that you add a Fiddle with your code as it would be easier to find out what's missing.

Comment: @dr_dev Updated your Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5aonn7qr/1/  with two adjustments: At Fiddle options, selected `normalized css` and added  `body tag` `<body>` (same setting is in the Fiddle from where you copied the content)

Comment: @dr_dev Sorry, just noticed that in fullscreen the issue persists. Adjusted fiddle in fullscreen: http://jsfiddle.net/5aonn7qr/4/embedded/result/  with the adjustment at the end of the fiddle css to set `float:none` to `.tabs-menu, .tab`

Comment: i also use this tab. it nice and small script. i want to how can make auto change one by one. say like each 5 sec next tab will active. something like slider

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
<ul class="tabs-menu" style="width:100%; margin-bottom:0px;">
```